# Pythonic way of creating a string + vs %

Tags: python, string, append

When creating a string out of many substrings what is more pythonic - + or %?

```
big_string = string1 + string2 + ... + stringN

big_string = ''
for i in range(n):
    big_string+=str(i)
```

or

```
big_string = "%s%s...%s" % (string1, string2, ... , stringN)

big_string = ''
for i in range(n):
    big_string = "%s%s" % (big_string, str(i))
```

Comment: Successive concatenation isn't just non-Pythonic, it's actually *degenerate*. Performance in older versions of Python can approach O(n**2).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: But in 2.7 or 3.x, performance is just fine, so I don't think you can call it "degenerate". But you're definitely right that it's non-pythonic for more than a handful of strings, or for any looping construct. (Which comes up in many recurring arguments on python-ideas and -dev, because it's one of the few example people can point to of a change made to the interpreter just to improve the way "bad" code works…)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
big_string = ''.join([string1, string2, ..., stringN])
```

Answer (score -2):

`big_string = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [string1, string2, ..., stringN], "")`

Comment: Heck no. `reduce` with a lambda, with quadratic performance, when `''.join` already exists and has been highly tuned for just this task?

Comment: @user2357112 concurred.